# Dell Poweredge 2900 can't find drives nor raidcard

Tags: windows, dell

I have a Dell power-edge 2900 server and I want to install windows server 2012 r2, but for some reason the server will not detect the hard drives. I am not so experienced with servers which is the reason why i got the server. I tried downloading drivers, but i have no clue which is the correct driver nor any idea on how to install them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that first and foremost, you need to initialize the disks and configure the RAID. Learn more following this:

[https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23620745/Dell-poweredge-server-windows-can't-see-the-hard-drives.html](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23620745/Dell-poweredge-server-windows-can%27t-see-the-hard-drives.html)

Here you can find out how to install an appropriate drivers with the Dell Download Manager:

https://www.dell.com/support/article/uk/en/ukdhs1/sln85570/how-to-install-device-drivers-with-the-dell-download-manager?lang=en

Hope that helps!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you for you noticing, Michael. I've edited my post according to your suggestions.